# Override variable in Razor view

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

Newly working with razor view and appreciate any suggestions. I have the following in the view:

```
Script.Require("Accounts");
var o = sidePanel.Entities.ToString(WorkContext.CurrentUser, false);

var t = sidePanel.Entities.Title;
<text>
    <article class="widget-aside-right widget-accounts-side-widget widget">
        <accounts-side-widget @o title="@t" />
    </article>
</text>
```

and the C# toString method is:

```
public string ToString(IUser user, bool isOpenDynamic = true)
{
    // todo (tba 11/3/15): why is groups always included?
    string options = (AllAccounts ? " allaccounts" : string.Empty)
                     + (EntityGroups ? " groups" : string.Empty)
                     + (Balance ? " balance" : string.Empty)
                     + (Number ? " number" : string.Empty)
                     + " isOpen=" + (IsOpen && isOpenDynamic)
                     + (ClientCode ? " clientCode" : string.Empty)
                     + (BaseCurrency ? " baseCurrency" : string.Empty)
                     + " missingdatareportid=" + MissingDataReportId
                     + (ReportBook && user.HasPermission(PermissionType.ReportBook) ? " reportbook" : string.Empty)
                     + (AccountDetailPopup ? " details" : string.Empty);

    return options;
}
```

I cannot change the variable in the backend because it will affect many other clients using the same backend but the view is specific to this client. Therefore, I need to be able to change the value of a certain variable (isOpen) in the view and not in the backend.

Read about setting the variable using Javascript and JQuery but saw this isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write another version of the ToString(..) method for that specific client, calling it ToStringForABCInc(...)  That way, you maintain the existing logic and views for other clients and have the specific view and logic for the client with the special requirement.

Comment: Its a good idea, but basically I can't edit the C# layer bse it need to be standard for all clients.

Comment: It will be. If the ToString method is being called from views, and the view in question is only in use by one client, the integrity of the project is maintained.  Or you could write a helper in the view I guess, but IMHO that stinks.  Why have a rule which doesn't achieve anything except having to find ways round it?

Comment: Will upvote. Didn't use this method but could have worked.